# aspnet core rc2 updating cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

i'm using authentication.cookie middle ware and I add a claim to a user.  But now that that user has that claim, i dont want them to log out and then back in for them to get an updated cookie with that claim.  How do I update the cookie?

[image]

i've tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: You can skip the SignOut call, SignIn should be sufficient. This creates an updated cookie containing the new claims for future requests.

Comment: I tried that, and it still is not working.  When I view the claims princiapal after calling

 await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", User);

I can see the claim inside there but when it returns the view, I lose that claim, the only way to get that claim back is by logging out and logging back in manually.